# View with @FetchRequest not reflecting changes in CloudKit database

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, cloudkit

I'm using CoreData + CloudKit in my app, and my views aren't reflecting changes in CloudKit. For example, when I delete records on the web CloudKit dashboard, they still show in my view in the simulator. Running the app again from Xcode still reflects old data in the simulator.

I was able to recreate this problem using the default Xcode project with CloudKit and CoreData boxes checked and minimal additions to Persistence.swift.

---

Here's that code

**Persistence.swift**

```swift
import CloudKit
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "TestProject")
        let containerIdentifier = "[MY CONTAINER IDENTIFIER]"
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
        // Default store
        let defaultStoreLocation = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url!
        
        // Setup public store
        let publicStoreLocation = defaultStoreLocation.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("public.sqlite")
        let publicStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: publicStoreLocation)
        publicStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(
            containerIdentifier: containerIdentifier)
        publicStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
        
        // Load persistent store descriptions
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [publicStoreDescription]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

---

And here's the default ContentView

**ContentView.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

---

Here's the default App

**TestProjectApp.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestProjectApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are getting started I recommend using the private database. There is a new feature of the Cloudkit dashboard to view the database of a different user. E.g. if your developer Apple ID is different from your personal Apple ID on your iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10650/ at around 14:00 on deleting items in the public database.

You would have to set a flag isTrashed for example and then filter items based on that instead of deleting them for the Public database.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I was working on this for a long time and thought I watched all the WWDC NSPersistentCloudKitContainer videos.